# Storing map/reduce results and accessing later?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have a collection with lots of data. I run map/reduce and store (merge) the results in a new collection. The map/reduce returns the results, which I can then access. But what if I want to access these results later on, or in a different controller? The results are in another collection, but not part of any model in my rails application. Is there a way I can access them after the fact from mongoid? The only way I have figured out is to drop to the Moped driver level and pull the results manually, but this does not seem clean.

```
Graph.mongo_session[:mr_results].find()
```

This works, but I would prefer if it could be referenced from my model somehow, like:

```
@my_graph.mr_results
```

This could be a 1:1 reference relationship, but I can't figure out if this is possible, or how I would set this up in my model.